# How to convert into function

Tags: php, arrays, function, phpmyadmin

I'm new in php, i need some help i want to convert my code into function anyone can suggestion how i can convert it into function.

```
//ERRORS
$Errors = array(
        2=>'The uploaded file exceeds',
        3=>'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.',
        4=>'No file selected',
        6=>'Missing a temporary folder.',
        7=>'Failed to write file to disk.'  
    );
//UPLOAD FILE
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_FILES['file'])){
        $File = $_FILES['file'];        
        $OutFiles = array();
        foreach($File as $Index=>$Items){
            foreach($Items as $Key=>$Item){
                $OutFiles[$Key][$Index] = $Item;
            }
        }
        if($OutFiles[0]['error']){
            $error = $Errors[$OutFiles[0]['error']];
        }else{
            foreach($OutFiles as $Index=>$File){
                $UploadDir = $DocRoot.'/upload/';
                $name = $File['name'];
                //FILE EXTENTION GETTING
                $file_ext = explode('.',$name);
                $file_ext = $file_ext[count($file_ext)-1];
                //FILE NAME
                $filename = (rand()).'-'.(time()).'.'.$file_ext;
                //FILE EXTENTION ERROR
                if($file_ext != "jpg" && $file_ext != "png" && $file_ext != "jpeg" && $file_ext != "gif"){
                    $error = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
                }elseif(move_uploaded_file($File['tmp_name'],$UploadDir.$filename)){
                    $OutFiles[$Index]['name'] = $filename;
                    $uploadok++;
                    $done = "uploaded";
                }elseif($uploadok == 0){
                    $error = "Sorry File is Not Upload";
                }else{
                    $uploadok--;
                    $error = "Sorry File is Not Upload";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Please anyone can suggestion how i can convert into function i'm little bit confuse about error variable like `array` and other one that how i can control and echo to my html from function

**HTML**

```
<?php if(!$ok):?>
    <?php echo $error; ?>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple/>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit"/>
    </form>
    <?php else: ?> 
    <div><h3>Done</h3></div>
        <?php
            foreach($filename as $file){
                echo "<div style='display:block; width:100px; height:100px; margin:0 10px; float:left; border:1px solid #eee;'><img style='width:auto; height:auto; max-width:100%; max-height:100%;' src='../upload/".$file['name']."' /></div>";
            }
        ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Follow MVC structure.. learn about OOPs. then use classes and functions.

Comment: yeah i'm reading about it but rightnow i'm just doing basic techniques so my teacher said convert into function now i did it file upload is working but its not showing any error on it

Comment: so you are looking for homework done.. :)

Comment: Try to start here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_functions.asp

Comment: :D yeah i have completed much but still confuse about error messages that how i will manage it via function

Comment: just return the error from the function using the "return" keyword. If you need to return multiple values at the same time, make a class with multiple properties and return an instance of that class.

Comment: @ADyson can you use my code and give example with it?